# Save epoch string to mysql datetime only year/month/date but no hour minute seconds

Tags: c++, mysql, datetime

I have some C++ code that saves an epoch string (converted from `time_t` object) to MySQL database `time` column (data type `datetime`).

The epoch time string in C++ is `1559333386`, however, when saved to MySQL, it only shows the date, with hour, minute and second all showing as zero: `2019-05-31 00:00:00`.

Question is how to save the epoch timestamp with the full info to MySQL database in `year-month-day hour:minute:second` format?

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
std::time_t t = std::stof(time);
std::stringstream sstime;
sstime << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&t), "%F") << '\n';
Poco::Data::Statement sql_insert(*session);
sql_insert << "INSERT into history (uid,  time) \
               VALUES (?,?)",
               Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(uid),

               Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(sstime.str());
```

Comment: Here is the code:

`std::time_t t = std::stof(time);

    std::stringstream sstime;

    sstime << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&t), "%F") << '\n';

 Poco::Data::Statement sql_insert(*session);
    sql_insert << "INSERT into history (uid,  time) \
                   VALUES (?,?)",
                   Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(uid),
                   Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(sstime.str());`

Comment: https://codeofmatt.com/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/

Comment: Also, please delete the code in comments.  If necessary you can edit your post instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

One is to do some pre-processing to the epoch timestamp to change its format to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`, and then bind it to the SQL statement.

The other one is a bit weird and risky in my opinion, I found it in the comment section of the [DATETIME documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) on MySQL website, here's how:

```sql
SET @@timestamp := 1559333386;
INSERT INTO history (time) VALUES (NOW());
SET @@timestamp := DEFAULT;
```

More about this in MySQL documentation for [timestamp system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_timestamp).

The above are just some recommendations, I didn't do any testing and validation not having desired environments, please do test it thoroughly before you implement it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i will try both method.